# Why aren't any of my pings being returned?

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless, internet

I'm playing around with the ping command in terminal but for some reason none of the pings I send are received apparently, if I `ping www.google.co.uk` it is always 100% packet loss, even though I can access *www.google.co.uk* just fine in firefox. `ping 0` is the only address that doesn't return 100% packet loss. How do I fix this? What exactly is wrong? for example I use "`ping www.google.co.uk`" and it sends out packets of 56(84) bytes of data but none of them are ever received.

The output of `sudo ufw status verbose` is `'status: inactive'`

The output of `date ; ping -c 4 www.google.co.uk ; dmesg -T | tail` is:

```
Fri Nov 20 11:37:19 GMT 2015
PING www.google.co.uk (216.58.208.35) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- www.google.co.uk ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3022ms
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A )
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm), (0 s)
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm), (N/A)
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:27 2015] wlan0: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by e0:1c:41:11:d8:29
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:28 2015] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:28 2015] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP: failed to evaluate _DSM
[Fri Nov 20 11:07:28 2015] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20140424/nsarguments-95)
[Fri Nov 20 11:09:49 2015] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
```

Comment: You have the ufw firewall enabled? Please [edit] your question with the output of `sudo ufw status verbose`. Also run `date && ping -c 4 www.google.co.uk && dmesg -T | tail` and paste its output to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, sorry! My fault. You need `date ; ping -c 4 www.google.co.uk ; dmesg -T | tail`, otherwise it does not print the `dmesg`. Please update your question and excuse my little mistake. :-)

Comment: Thanks. This output however does not contain the error I had in mind, so I unfortunately don't know how to proceed from this point on. I am no networking expert, so I'm out. Good luck.

Comment: Can you attempt a `traceroute www.google.co.uk`?  You may need to install traceroute first:  `sudo apt-get install traceroute`

Answer (score -1):

Sometime over the past several years I have noticed that google domains (WITH THE ISP's I personally use) no longer respond to ICMP traffic which is how ping works. 
I assume this is by design.

Can you ping your gateway?

Comment: I checked this, and www.google.co.uk does respond to pings for me.

Comment: Interesting. On both my home and work ISP that is not that case.

Comment: I think it's probably some middle point router, configured to block pings.  A typical route from myself to www.google.co.uk takes 10 hops

Comment: @CharlesGreen The sum total of our experience indicates that It, at the very least, could also be the case ICMP to google.co.uk is blocked for him as well.

Comment: I also can't get but the first few hops out of my traceroutes (even when I could ping google.com). It is likely my ISP, but I know they have a ton of customers.

Comment: @ediitdunn - I agree, it just seems that in his case a router very close to his system is blocking all ping on standard ports.

Comment: @CharlesGreen haha I should change my handle for sure... Just getting warmed up here.. I hope I can become as polished as so many of the folks here one day! :)

Comment: Sorry bout that!